# telerik radgrid hierachy linkbutton click error

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

Hi I got an error when try to click the linkbutton at the column. This error only occur when I expand all the detail table at the same time. The error shown is Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Below is my codes. Please help. Thanks

```
   Protected Sub lnkID_Select(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

            Dim MerchantID As String = ""
            Dim BranchNum As String = ""

            Dim dt As GridDataItem = DirectCast(sender, LinkButton).NamingContainer
            MerchantID = CType(RadGrid1.Items(dt.ItemIndex).FindControl("lnkMerchantID"), LinkButton).Text
            BranchNum = CType(RadGrid1.Items(dt.ItemIndex).FindControl("BranchNum"), Label).Text

            Response.Redirect("~/Master/Merchant/MerchantDetail.aspx?MerchantID=" & MerchantID & "&BranchNum=" & BranchNum & "")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the line that throws the error?

Comment: This line throw error          MerchantID = CType(RadGrid1.Items(dt.ItemIndex).FindControl("lnkMerchantID"), LinkButton).Text

Answer (score 0):

The only reasons you would get that error, for this line:

```
MerchantID = CType(RadGrid1.Items(dt.ItemIndex).FindControl("lnkMerchantID"), LinkButton).Text
```

RadGrid1.Items(dt.ItemIndex) - this returns null, but most likely, if out of range, a different error would be thrown.
FindControl("lnkMerchantID") - This returns null, or a type other than LinkButton.  If not a LinkButton, it would return null from the CType.

Those are the only possible reasons, with the most likely culprit being that it can't find lnkMerchantID.